# Generate a formula to calculate affect on continously compound interest if a constant salary is continously added to principle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm feeling stupid with a simple algebra question.  I'm hoping someone can help me figure out why something I know should be obvious just isn't clicking for me.

I won't go into actual details of the scenario I'm trying to calculate, but effectively the part I need help on can be molded by continuously compounded interest:

$A=P e^{rt}$

Except that I have the option to accept a lower rate $r$ for a small constant amount of power to be added continuously.  If you think of the above as the interest my bank is giving me then you could imagine some salary $S$ being added every day to my bank account as well, with me wanting to figure out my final amount at the end of time interval $T$ considering both interest and salary.  This means including interest on my salary, and the interest on the interest on the salary etc as salary is constantly being added to my principle.  I'm also looking for an equation in which everything is compounded continuously, not on an interval like my once-a-day example.

Can anyone help me figure out how I would create an equation to consider the extra salary $S$, and then adjust the formula to calculate how to compare $R$ and $S$ if I want to figure out at what point I would break even in profits by the end of constant time interval $T$ if I accepted a drop in rate $R$ for an increase in salary $S$?

Honestly I'm more interested in what step I'm missing in my algebra to figure out how to add a factor $S$ than what the final equation is.  I'm feeling silly that the only approach I can think of feels like way more work than should be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are having trouble is that the problem is not all that easy, certainly not at the pre-calulus level.

Say the account starts at $x_0$ and there is a constant salary rate $s$ and an interest rate $t$.  Then if we knew calculus the equation for $x(t)$ would be
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = rx+s
$$
and the solution generically would be 
$$
\int \frac{dx}{rx+s} = dt \\
\frac1r\log(rx+s) = t+C \\
rx+s = e^{rC} e^{rt} \\
x = \frac{e^{rC}}{r} e^{rt} - \frac{s}{r} 
$$
Since $x(0) = x_0$ we can determine the value of the constant $C$:
$$
x_0 = \frac{e^{rC}}{r} -\frac{s}{r} \\
e^{rC} = rx_0 + s 
$$
And thus 
$$
x(t) = (x_0+\frac{s}{r})e^{rt} - \frac{s}{r}
$$
I don't think most people could come to this solution without calculus.

And to determine, for a fixed $s$ and $T$, what no-salary interest rate $R$ is equivalent to some with-salary interest rate $r$, we have to solve for $R$ in 
$$
x_0 e^{RT} = (x_0+\frac{s}{r})e^{rT} - \frac{s}{r}
$$
The solution is 
$$
R = \frac{1}{T} \left[ \log\left((x_0+\frac{s}{r})e^{rT} - \frac{s}{r}\right) - \log x_0 \right]
$$

Comment: thank you.  That is basically the approach I started down, before deciding it was getting way to complicated and I must be doing something wrong.  Calculus has always been my weakest math, even compared to some of the later 400 level courses I took.